# android: stretch image in imageview to fit screen

Tags: android, imageview

I have an `imageview` that has its height and width set to `fill_parent` with a `linearlayout` that has the same values set. So I suppose this should set my images to fit the screen. But it only fits like 80% (margin top and bottom in landscape mode).

I've tried the following code without success:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

imgView.setMinimumWidth(width);
imgView.setMinimumHeight(height);

imgView.setMaxWidth(width);
imgView.setMaxHeight(height);
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Although it's a slightly different problem, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991110/android-how-to-stretch-an-image-to-the-screen-width-while-maintaining-aspect-rat/2999707#2999707) should help you.

Answer (score 332, accepted):

to change pro-grammatically use :

```
imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

**OR**

to change from xml use:

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: I know this is what you wanted, but for images where you care about aspect ratio, this will stretch it out.

Comment: Works wonders for ImageView inside a ScrollView. Even the aspect is kept correct.

Comment: The same can be defined in the layout xml, android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: Now my pictures look fat

Comment: To make the image fill all the area and keep a good aspect ratio use `v.setAdjustViewBounds(true); v.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);`

Comment: @MarcoFlorian Why not just use FIT_CENTER? Is there any reason?

Comment: @Jenix `FIT_CENTER` will fit it horizontally or vertically leaving the rest of the area empty. https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8SBHoA5e0M4/VeFSX8HX7qI/AAAAAAAAbI0/z2STMO_cAeY/s1600/AndroidImageViewScaleType_Fit_Center.png

Comment: @MarcoFlorian Yeah, I know what FIT_CENTER and CENTER_CROP are, and that's why I'm using FIT_CENTER most of the time over CENTER_CROP in my apps so far. But I didn't know about the 'v.setAdjustViewBounds(true)' thing so tried with CENTER_CROP as you did, and surprisingly, it worked just like FIT_CENTER. I'm happy to know new thing but asked you the question because if there's any reason writing two lines over one line..

Comment: @Jenix, didn't notice this comment till now. `v.setAdjustViewBounds(true)` will make it fit the area boundaries if the image is bigger or smaller. `FIT_CENTER` or `CENTER_CROP` are applied then. Do your tests with small and big images, you will notice the differences this way.

Comment: @Marco Florian Thanks for the reply. When I asked the question, I was working with some projects and tested on one of it. I don't know which one it was, and don't remember I actually tested with both bigger and smaller images even though I think I would, and did. So I gave it another try with an empty project, but this confuses me more.. Calling setAdjustViewBounds() with both true and false doesn't affect at all.

Comment: Whether it's true or not, setting to ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP is always CENTER_CROP, and setting to ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER is always FIT_CENTER. At that time, I asked you purely out of curiosity but I think I need to take some time trying many different cases. Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm

Answer (score 119):

Give in the xml file of your layout `android:scaleType="fitXY"`
P.S : this applies to when the image is set with `android:src="..."` rather than `android:background="..."` as backgrounds are set by default to stretch and fit to the View.

Comment: the background thing didn't help solve the problem for me, am i doing something wrong?
please take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164473/imageview-is-not-stretching-to-fit-the-screen

Comment: This doesnt take care of aspect ratio if you hardcode the images' width and want the height to scale

Comment: How can I get this to fit the whole screen then? I want it to still be proportional

Comment: +1 for telling it applies to android:src="..." rather than android:background="..." this is very important

Answer (score 22):

use this:

```
ImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Comment: This in combination with `android:scaleType="fitXY"` is what worked. Thanks

Comment: @smac89 What is the difference between those combination and just using FIT_CENTER? Should not use FIT_CENTER?

Comment: @Jenix, mind you it's been a while since I last touched Android, but I believe the reason for doing `fitXY` is so that the image is stretched proportionally to fit the frame/view it was set in. Using `FIT_CENTER` sounds like it will just place the image in the center of the view but does not fill the view. I may be wrong, but you can experiment with either to find out what works

Comment: @smac89 Before asking I already tested both of them and it worked just the same. I was curious about the reason but now think you didn't know FIT_CENTER just like the fact I didn't know about the combination you let me know. :)

Answer (score 9):

if you use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` then you must specify

`android:layout_width="75dp"` and `android:layout_height="75dp"`

if use wrap_content it will not stretch to what you need

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="75dp"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:id="@+id/listItemNoteImage"
android:src="@drawable/MyImage"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is perfect, however if you want to do it from xml, you can use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 2):

I Have used this `android:scaleType="fitXY"` code in Xml file.

Answer (score 0):

just change your ImageView height and width to wrap_content and use

exampleImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

in your code.

Answer (score 0):

for XML android

```
android:src="@drawable/foto1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is irrelevant.
This how I do it on android studio.

Put this in the xml:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"

android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

adjustViewBounds = will fit the image according to the ratio

scaleType = crop out all the white empty spaces

Then, set the

```
layout_width = match_parent 
layout_height = warp_content
```

[will become like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQaO2.png)

Answer (score -11):

Trying using :

```
imageview.setFitToScreen(true);
imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

This will fit your imageview to the screen with the correct ratio.

Comment: "imageview.setFitToScreen(true);" - what is that? some undocumented method?

Comment: I am using eclipse and this does not compile: `imageview.setFitToScreen(true)`

Comment: There is no such method like this in the android.

Comment: Maybe he meant `setFitsSystemWindows()` ??