# android XML scrollview and linear layout problem

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-linearlayout, fill-parent

I have the following code:

```
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ducks_r2_c1"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ducks_r3_c1"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true"/>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ducks_r4_c1"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true"/>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ducks_r5_c1"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true"/>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ducks_r6_c1"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:clickable="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I have used layout_width="fill_parent" everywhere. But this is the screenshot of how it shows up on the emulator. 
[image]

I dont want the space on either side of the images. 
Why is it showing up like this? How can I rectify it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is happening because the image is not streching.

You may try to ask the image to strech itself:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

or use it as background.

please check this thread:
[android: stretch image in imageview to fit screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668001/android-stretch-image-in-imageview-to-fit-screen)

Comment: let me try this and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

A ScrollView will only inflate to as many items are in it.

You should be able to solve this by using a LinearLayout (or another more predictable layout) as the parent for your ScrollView with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and setting the ScrollView to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and the same for layout_width on both.

Comment: let me try this and let you know

Comment: Thank you. That did not work. android:scaleType="fitXY" worked though. Thanks for the help anyway.