# imageView is not stretching to fit the screen

Tags: android

I have a drawable, which needs to work as the background. It needs to stretch to fill the screen (ignoring the aspect ratio).

I have provided appropriate sizes for ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi. 
(I know they are appropriate by the ratio of the corresponding widths and heights, is that enough?)

I have tried to do this as follows:

***using scaleType:fitXY on the imageView***

> This does leaves a white margin around (inside?) the imageView.

[image: fitXY image]

***A work around that I'm not satisfied with is using centre for the scaleType like this:***

I'm not satisfied because the problem still exists on tablet screens.
[image]

***Note:***

- As you might have noticed, I have tried the suggested fixes elsewhere
  on SO like setting Adjust View Boundaries to true. They didn't help
  here. :(
- I would like a non-programmatic answer/fix, as in doing this in XML itself. I wouldn't really want to be writing code to set a background image; Life should be much simpler than that. (:P)

***Update 1:***

Here's the XML Layout

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" -->
    <!-- xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" -->
    <!-- android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1" -->
    <!-- android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
    <!-- android:layout_height="fill_parent" -->
    <!-- tools:context=".SplashScreen" > -->


    <!--
         This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows
    -->

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:onClick="onClickTapToContinue"
         >
    </View>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bg_gradient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/this_is_the_background_image"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_gradient" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bg_artwork"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/artwork_man"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_artwork" />

    <!-- </FrameLayout> -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/branding"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/branding_text"
        android:maxHeight="95dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/title_wlcm" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/tap_continue"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</merge>
```

Comment: let me add that i've tried other scaleType options and those don't seem to fix it. (as seen in the WYSIWYG editor)

Comment: you can try to add background to the parent LinearLayout itself by usig `android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"` with `layout_width` and `layout_height` equals `"match_parent"` .

Comment: @pyus13 I have tried that but that really didn't help. I got similar results.
And the reason I'm using framelayout here is that: 1) I can "merge" and eliminate one level of view hierarchy 2) the gradient, the man, branding are all different images which need to be overlapped

Comment: Is something wrong with the images themselves? How can I tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hack I'm going with for now is using these set of images as is for phones and maybe another set of images(and layouts?) for WVGA(Tablets).

> Haven't tried this yet though. I'll post with screenshots as soon as I
>   do.

Edit: Figures it had to do with the images themselves. There was transparent padding. Will ask designer to fix it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using android:src="...", use android:background="..." attribute. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the graphical layout of the activity in eclipse, you can right click on the activity and then select "edit background". This will allow you to set the picture as the back ground, which covers all edges of the screen. 
Hope this helps, cheers Jim

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But doesn't it just set the src of the background to this image? Still showing the defects of the image if any. (as posted in my answer; should I move that part to the Q?)