# ImageView to scale to fixed height, but crop excess width

Tags: android, android-imageview

I would like my [`ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) to scale in a particular fashion:

- Scale so that the height of the image always fits the height of the `ImageView`
- Crop any excess width

A picture speaks louder than a 1000 words, so here is a representation of how I want my `ImageView` to behave. Suppose it has a fixed height of say 100dp and suppose its width is `match_parent`.

[image]

Note that

- on the phone layout, the image height is stretched, but the sides are cropped, akin to `CROP_CENTER`.
- on the tablet layout, the image is also stretched to fit the `ImageView` height, behaving like `FIT_CENTER`

I suspect I need `scaleType:matrix`, but after that I'm lost. How can I make sure an image fits Y, but crops X?

Comment: could you provide a screen shot of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Umm... Don't you understand my paint creation?

Comment: sorry but no i dont , please provide your source code as well

Comment: you paint creation was good enough, but this one is great!

Comment: @Amrola you're trolling!

Comment: @Maarten no , but sorry .

Comment: In xml, use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` .. thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/a/15600295/2162226

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a little help from my friends Carlos Robles and pskink, came up with the following custom `ImageView`:

```
public class FitYCropXImageView extends ImageView {
    boolean done = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public FitYCropXImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public FitYCropXImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public FitYCropXImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    private final RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, 0,0);
    private final RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, 0,0);
    private final Matrix m = new Matrix();
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (done) {
            return;//Already fixed drawable scale
        }
        final Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d == null) {
            return;//No drawable to correct for
        }
        int viewHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        int viewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int drawableWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int drawableHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        drawableRect.set(0, 0, drawableWidth, drawableHeight);//Represents the original image
        //Compute the left and right bounds for the scaled image
        float viewHalfWidth = viewWidth / 2;
        float scale = (float) viewHeight / (float) drawableHeight;
        float scaledWidth = drawableWidth * scale;
        float scaledHalfWidth = scaledWidth / 2;
        viewRect.set(viewHalfWidth - scaledHalfWidth, 0, viewHalfWidth + scaledHalfWidth, viewHeight);

        m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER /* This constant doesn't matter? */);
        setImageMatrix(m);

        done = true;

        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont think that Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER will work, does it really work?

Comment: For me it does... I don't have a deep insight in the `setRectToRect` method, but if looks fine on my device! (As does `STRETCH`.)

Comment: indeed as two rects have the same aspect ratio **any** ScaleToFit will work

Comment: great! it works also for a FitXCropYImageView, croping the height while filling with the width.

Comment: Can you please tell me what changes I have to make to get FitXCropYImageView ?

Answer (score 27):

In xml, use:

```
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

from & thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15600295/2162226

Answer (score 1):

If you use `scaleType:matrix` you will need to create your own [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) and asign it to the view by means of `setImageMatrix(Matrix)` or manually modify the matrix at hen onMEasure method of a customImageView.

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView   {

 boolean done=false;

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (done)
            return;

        final Drawable d = getDrawable();
        final int drawableW = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        final int drawableH = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        float ratio =  drawableW / drawableH;

        //int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();

        float scale=height/drawableH;

          Matrix m = getImageMatrix();

          float[] f = new float[9];
          m.getValues(f);

          f[Matrix.MSCALE_X]=scale;
          f[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]=scale;

          m.setValues(f);  

        done = true;

        requestLayout();

    }

}
```

Comment: yeah, thats why you adjust the height in the onmeasure method. aslo you change the width to keep the ratio, and since the scaletype is center_crop, if the widht is too much, it will be cropped

Comment: if you give me a second i will explain how to do it.

Comment: finally i took the time and write a solution working with the matrix. i think it will work well in any case

Comment: Wow... Didn't expect to get so low-level. Thanks!

Comment: But what if the drawable is not yet set at measure?

Comment: until they build the scaletype:fitX or scaletype:fitY, im afraid we have to go low level!

Comment: you can check for that, after of `if (done)` and return if there isn't drawable. The system will keep calling onMeasure.  Also you can migrate this code to your activity, and do all the maths after you assign the drawable. Of course the functions would be different, but the logic would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LayoutParams params;

    final ImageView iv0 = new ImageView(this);
    //iv0.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
    ll.addView(iv0, params);

    final ImageView iv1 = new ImageView(this);
    //iv1.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00);
    params = new LayoutParams(60, 100);
    ll.addView(iv1, params);

    setContentView(ll);

    Runnable action = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer0);
            int dw = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int dh = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, dw, dh);

            ImageView[] iviews = {iv0, iv1};
            for (int i = 0; i < iviews.length; i++) {
                ImageView iv = iviews[i];
                iv.setImageDrawable(d);
                iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

                float h = iv.getHeight();
                float w = iv.getWidth();
                float cx = w / 2;
                float scale = h / dh;
                float deltaw = dw * scale / 2;
                RectF dst = new RectF(cx - deltaw, 0, cx + deltaw, h);
                Matrix m = new Matrix();
                m.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.FILL);
                iv.setImageMatrix(m);
            }
        }
    };
    iv1.post(action);
```

Comment: Some word of explanation, maybe? What if the drawable is not yet set at the end of the `ImageView` message queue?

Comment: what you mean by "if the drawable is not yet set" ?

Comment: You perform `iv.setImageDrawable(d);` in the `Runnable`. What if the drawable is fetched asynchronously from the internet and you have no guarantee about layout having happened when you get your hands on it, and conversely, having the drawable when layout occurs.

Comment: i use Runnable only because i need to make sure that ImageViews are already layout and have non zero width & height, you can assign your image Drawable any time you want provided that ImageView is non zero sized (you can also do it by extending ImageView and overriding onSizeChanged)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the center of the image, use:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

If you want to show the edge of the image instead of the center, use:

```
android:scaleType="matrix"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```