# Android ImageView scale bitmap to the width and crop the height

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have a fixed size `ImageView`. I want to achieve this :

1. Scale the `Bitmap` always to the width, if the `Bitmap` is wider or smaller than `Imageview` width.
2. Crop the height if taller than `ImageView` height else scale it to the height.

I want something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21434624/1129612), but the other way around (FitXCropY). I have tried changing this answer with no success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this answer [ImageView to scale to fixed height, but crop excess width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426000/imageview-to-scale-to-fixed-height-but-crop-excess-width/21434624#21434624)

```
public class FitXCropYImageView extends ImageView {
boolean done = false;

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public FitXCropYImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public FitYCropXImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public FitXCropYImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)      {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

private final RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, 0,0);
private final RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, 0,0);
private final Matrix m = new Matrix();
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (done) {
        return;//Already fixed drawable scale
    }
    final Drawable d = getDrawable();
    if (d == null) {
        return;//No drawable to correct for
    }
    int viewHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    int viewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int drawableWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int drawableHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
    drawableRect.set(0, 0, drawableWidth, drawableHeight);//Represents the original image
    //Compute the left and right bounds for the scaled image
    float viewHalfHeight = viewHeight / 2;
    float scale = (float) viewWidth / (float) drawableWidth;
    float scaledHeight = drawableHeight * scale;
    float scaledHalfHeight = scaledHeight / 2;
    viewRect.set(0, viewHalfHeight-scaledHalfHeight,viewWidth, viewHalfHeight+scaledHalfHeight);

    m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER /* This constant doesn't matter? */);
    setImageMatrix(m);

    done = true;

    requestLayout();
}
}
```

Comment: Does not work. Smaller images are cropped and scaled to fit the screen. I want the image to be cropped only if the height is larger than imageview height. All other cases the image should be scaled up or down.

Comment: You can use Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL if the image height is less than your imageview's height and use Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER if is it's bigger than imageview's height.

Comment: Is working for my use case of cropping larger images

Answer (score -1):

Try like this,

Add inside Oncreate

```
viewImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureImageview123);
viewImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: Thanks , but I think FIT_XY will scale down the Bitmap height if it is taller than ImageView height, but I want it to be cropped.