# How to scale the height but cut off the end of an image in Android ImageView?

Tags: android, image, imageview, scale, android-screen

This more of a conceptual Android question

Say I have this static image that I want to load into an ImageView -[image]

Say the image is 600px by 200px.(width by height)

Say my image view I try fitting it into is 300 px by 200px(width by height)

I just want to scale by height and cut off the left end of the image so that the image can fit into the imageview. Also if no cuts need to take place(fits already), I don't want to cut any of it off.

So in the end the ImageView(if it was 300 px by 200px) would hold this image

[image]
(basically so the F doesn't get distorted)

I've looked [Scale To Fit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#END) but none of the scale types seems to achieve this custom effect. Does anyone know of how I would go about this? In my case, I wouldn't want to maintain the original aspect ratio.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21434624/3541465: checkout following link, this might help

Comment: try to use negative padding / layout_margin values

Comment: @Aakash which scaletype from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html should i use. All of them maintain the original aspect ratio

Comment: @Anton why not custom image view?

Comment: You should use center scale type.

Comment: @Aakash and in the xml file should i define this new ImageView's scaleType to Matrix? I did so and nothing happened

Comment: Actually defining in xml would not make any difference because you to  process your image, scale type adjusts the imageview size according to the view. It does not make dimension changes in bitmap. So you should crop your image by following the link i mentioned in comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should crop the Bitmap so that it always fits into your ImageView. If you want the bottom-right corner cropped, you could do something similar to this:

```
if (needsCropping()) {
    int startWidth = originalImage.getWidth() - 300;
    int startHeight = originalImage.getHeight() - 200;


    Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, startWidth, startHeight, width, height);

    // TODO set imageview
}
```

Comment: Would you need to create a custom image view for this approach?

Comment: You could create a custom image view if you're using it in several different places, but it's not a requirement.

Comment: How would you scale according to height first?

Comment: The scaled bitmap should match the width & height of the ImageView exactly, so you don't need to set scaleType flags

Answer (score 0):

FIT_END would do this: 
Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. END aligns the result to the right and bottom edges of dst.

You can use ScaleType.CENTER_CROP BUT this will not rescale the image in any way.

Any combinations of those is impossible, for that you must have your own scale method (subclassing ImageView).

Or, the easy way would have .9PNGs as the source of the image, it would fit any space without distorcing.

Comment: I tried FIT_END. The width(x axis) fit exactly. But the issue was that the Y didn't at all and there was all this space at the top. Do you know a way around that?

Comment: You have two options, override ImageView or use a 9PathPNG that would be easier.