# Differences between BitmapFactory.decodeResource and BitmapFactory.decodeStream

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, scaling

I've got an if-else scenario where the if-path uses this code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId, options);
```

And the else-path uses this code:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.fromFile(file));
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
```

Now to me, reading the short description from the API, testing and Googling I can't quite figure out the difference, but there seems to be a suble one.

The first piece of code scales to fit the width of the screen when applied to a ImageView (within a RelativeLayout, within a ScrollView). The second piece of code does not, which is my problem. It seems to loose it's aspect ratio somehow as well, because if I apply:

```
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

It manages to fit it to the width, but messes up the height (making it shorter than it should be). **Any input would be greatly appreciated!**

(I've already tried to change the first piece of code to see if I had messed something else up, but this rewrite of the if-path gave the same error:)

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable = true;
bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(resourceId), null, options);
```

Comment: Well, if your source image and imageview are different aspect ratios... won't using ScaleType.FIT_XY mess with the aspect ratio to make it fit? Have yo utried the other scale types, e.g. FIT_CENTER or FIT_INSIDE?

Comment: I hadn't tried it, but did now and no luck. Also, that is why I've got imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true) to make the ImageView adjust to the bitmaps-aspect ratio, but it doesn't when I'm using decodeStream.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem using this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677269/how-to-stretch-three-images-across-the-screen-preserving-aspect-ratio