# Android ImageView: Fit Width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I download image and set it as a screen background dynamically using `Imageview`. I have tried `ScaleType`, to scale the image.

If image height is larger than width then `ScaleTypes` `fitStart`, `fitEnd` and `fitCenter` don't work. Android scale down the photo and fit it based on the height, but I see some extra blank space as part of the width.

I want to scale down the photo based on the width so that it fits the width and I don't care if there's some extra blank space as part of the height or if height is too long it is fine if it's going out of the view(if that's possible?).

`ScaleType.XY` scale the photo and fit everything in the `ImageView` and doesn't care about image height/weight ratio.

```
<ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
            />
```

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I ended up using this code:

```
<ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/name"
            />
```

Make sure you set the image using `src` instead of `background`.

Comment: This isn't proportional though, it just crops the image to fit... How can I fix this?

Comment: Oh, okay. THanks for the response. So it's impossible to fit an image proportionally on a screen?

Comment: What do you suggest I do? I want to have an image (full screen) in my app. The image appears stretched out. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Sharj From what I can tell, it's `"fitCenter"` instead of `"centerFit"`.

Answer (score 84):

`android:adjustViewBounds="true"` does the job!

Answer (score 14):

This elegant solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677269/how-to-stretch-three-images-across-the-screen-preserving-aspect-ratio/4688335#4688335) will work like a charm for you.

Basically you just have to create a small class that extends `ImageView` and simply override the `onMeasure` method to adjust the width and height as you want. Here it scales to fit width by using:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = width * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

You would use this special `ImageView` like this:

```
<your.activity.package.AspectRatioImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/test" />
```

Comment: I have a ListView containing images downloaded on the fly. So adapter returns a layout with ImageView which size can change dynamically. This was the only approach that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: this isn't elegant at all, this is pretty hacky. look at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

There is a simple method if you simply want to fill the width of screen and have height proportional (and know the ratio of the image) you can do this in OnCreate():

```
setContentView(R.layout.truppview_activity);
trupImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trupImage);

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
float scWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels;
trupImage.getLayoutParams().width = (int) scWidth;
trupImage.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (scWidth * 0.6f);
```

Where 0.6 is the ratio adjustment (you could also calc automatically of course if you know the w & h of image).

PS:
Here is the XML side:

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/trupImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Answer (score 8):

if you want to fit the image whole parent block
it will stretch the image

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

And if you want to fit image whole parent with original ratio of image 
it will crop out some part of image

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me.

Create a class extends ImageView

```
    package com.yourdomain.utils;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {

        public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            Drawable d = getDrawable();

            if (d != null) {
                int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
                setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
            } else {
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }
    }
```

In xml use the following instead of ImageView

```
    <com.yourdomain.utils.ResizableImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/test" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cant do it only with XML, you need to resize yourself, the bitmap

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();

        try {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background))
                    .setImageBitmap(ShrinkBitmap(width));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

then

```
private Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(int width)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.img, bmpFactoryOptions);
    int widthRatio = (int) android.util.FloatMath
            .ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth / (float) width);


    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;



    if (bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize <= 0)
        bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 0;
    bmpFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.img, bmpFactoryOptions);
    return bitmap;

}
```

And the layout

```
 <ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
```