# Android imageview, scale full screen, and centerCrop

Tags: android, imageview

How can I have an imageview whose image fills the screen, but maintains its aspect ratio, and fits in the center?

Currently I have large images, larger than phone screen resolution, but I suspect that they will be be letterboxed on devices with higher resolution

What combination of `scaleType` will do the trick?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could simply use [`adjustViewBounds`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3aadjustViewBounds) value to maintain the aspect ratio of the image

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/metallicaImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/metallica" />
```

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" is also used

Answer (score 2):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

It's a basic setting.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before, the issue is that when the image needs to be scaled up (screen width is larger than the image), Android won't scale the image beyond its given size. However, scaling down works just fine.

I ended up creating the `AspectRatioImageView` mentioned below, works well. Be sure to read the comments about `getIntrinsicWidth()` returning 0 and `getDrawable()` returning null, and put in some safety checks for those.

[How to stretch three images across the screen preserving aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677269/how-to-stretch-three-images-across-the-screen-preserving-aspect-ratio)