# Android: ImageView scale to screen width within a ScrollView

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview, image-scaling

I'm quite new to android programming and I stumbled upon a problem with my `layout`.

At first, I had a `Linearlayout` with a `textview`, 2 `buttons` and a `imageview` **scaled** to fit the screen.

Now I wanted to put this under a `scrollview`, so the `imageview` could be scaled **larger** (to the width of the screen).

Without the `scrollview` everything just went fine, but with the `scrollview`, my `imageview` is not scaled anymore.

What am I doing **wrong**? I tried numerous solutions on **StackOverflow** but I can't get it to work with a `ScrollView`. Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/pageno" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/texta" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/textb" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/page1" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677269/how-to-stretch-three-images-across-the-screen-preserving-aspect-ratio
This answered my question, thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Make LinearLayout/RelativeLayout as parent view. In that make a scroll view and set alignparentTop=true. This scrollView will contain a single layout in which all other views will be placed.

Comment: Thanks for helping!
I tried RelativeLayout as parent view, then ScrollView as child with layout_alignParentTop=true and a LinearLayout(which contains all text/button/imageviews) as a child from ScrollView. But still no change. Also I get the warning the ScrollView is useless. I must be doing something wrong!