# How to Preserve aspect ratio of a button's background image with xml

Tags: android

I have a set of `Buttons` (not `ImageButtons`) declared in xml. They contain a background image. I want to be able to dictate the width of the `Button` via xml, via the use of weight... but I want to let the height to be dictated by the aspect ratio of the image.

I saw a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677269/how-to-stretch-three-images-across-the-screen-preserving-aspect-ratio/4688335#4688335), to which the answer involved the addition of `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` but the question concerned `ImageViews` rather than `Buttons` and when I tried the same additions to my `Button` code, it didn't appear to work.

Can what I want be achieved?

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

in layout of your Button or ImageButton (It's better if you use ImageButton).

Comment: I wanted to use a Button rather than an ImageButton because I wanted to have some text (a number) on it. I know I could have the number included on the image but the number could be anything from 1 to 40, - that's a lot of images.

Comment: scaleType is a property of ImageButton but not of Button.