# Center image horizontal in imageView without centering it vertically

Tags: android

I have images with dynamical dimensions and `ImageView` with statistical height.
I'm trying to bind my image in my `imageView` like this.

[ImageLink](http://i62.tinypic.com/2rftpoi.jpg)

[image]
I mean to fill the `ImageView` horizontally, but not vertically. Here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="280dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exploreImage"
        android:src="@drawable/beard1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But there is now `ScaleType` in `ImageView`, that allows this way to bind.

Do you have any idea about how to do it?

Comment: where is the image Man!

Comment: You have enough reputation to upload image in the question. Please do so.

Comment: hey this pic is not belonging u i think which u want to do i think u add some pics in horizontally like android image gallery Is is

Comment: Here I uplodaded an image, but it doesnt show it correctly =\

Comment: Do you want to scroll it?

Comment: @Tim,  I dont.
It is an item in listView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place it inside a `scrollview` and change your `imageview` code to this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/exploreImage"
    android:src="@drawable/beard1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
/>
```

Comment: Well, its a very nice idea, but it has a padding in the top of scrollView Oo

Comment: you can create your own class, this answer will help you a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4688335/1182971

Comment: Nice, thank you a lot
I've already found the solution without creating a new class. Just add to your answer 
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
And I will accept it

Comment: Hah, I implemented this in my code, and than I have another trouble, can you help again?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783536/onitemclick-doesnt-work-if-there-is-scrollview-on-layout

Comment: you should have said that this is an item of your listview, listview and scrollview don't get along.

Comment: Right, I had to notice it. Anyway I learned another way to do it) Now I will try to create a new class..

Answer (score 0):

Following xml produces very similar output to what you want. Just give the desired height lower than the height of the image.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:src="@drawable/image_1" />
```

In fact, `ScaleType.Matrix` means scaling using the image matrix which you should later provide in code when drawing. When you set `scaleType="matrix"` but provide no matrix in code; then it does not  scale but crop the image starting from top.

Comment: But it crop it horizontally also. I need to fill horizontally