# android image view in list will not scale to width

Tags: android, android-layout

New to Android, bad with layouts so this is probably a simple solution but I can't find it. I am adding an image to a ListView, the ListView is defined like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Image is added like this:

```
    ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    return image;
```

in the ListAdapter. I want the Image to scale so the width fills the screen and the height adjust proportionally. What is happening is the image is scaling down so the height fills the list row but there is plenty of room for the width to be bigger. I had this working earlier but can't figure out what changed. Why is the image shrinking to some seemingly arbitrary height and how do I get it to fill the screen by width?

Edit:

So this happened when I started building for 1.6 instead of 1.5, probably a resolution thing. I guess the image is a bit sharper when it's small but I want it larger, it's almost unusable smaller and I am not able to get a larger image, it's from the web.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no really "simple" solution, but it's already answered here (without list's, but i don't think it matters):
[Android: How to stretch an image to the screen width while maintaining aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991110/android-how-to-stretch-an-image-to-the-screen-width-while-maintaining-aspect-rat)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY  ?

[Scale Types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: yeah, it keeps the height the same as what it is now and stretches the image to the width of the screen. I want the height to adjust proportionally with the width, I don't know why the height is staying at what it is.

Comment: Oh, so you want the image to fill the entire width and have the height be whatever it ends up being proportionally?  Sorry I guess I misread your original question.  I'm not sure exactly how to do that.  How are you adding it to the List or Adapter?

Comment: when the list adapter getView is called I return that ImageView, I thought FIT_CENTER was supposed to do exactly what I'm looking for and it did for a while, I don't know what has changed