# Android ImageView adjusting parent's height and fitting width

Tags: android, resize, imageview

**Update** : I solved this issue by using the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991110/android-how-to-stretch-an-image-to-the-screen-width-while-maintaining-aspect-rat)

I'm a bit stuck with this issue, which I think should be pretty simple.

So my app downloads an image, and renders the bitmap in an ImageView, a child element of a RelativeLayout.
I would like the ImageView to fit the parent width, and to adapt it's size to keep the aspect ratio.

Here is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/banner" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    RelativeLayout banner = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner);
    ImageView imgV = new ImageView(this);

    imgV.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    // I tried all the scale types : CENTER_INSIDE : same effect, FIT_CENTER : same effect... 

    imgV.setBackgroundColor(0x00FFFF00);

    imgV.setAdjustViewBounds(Color.BLUE);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    banner.addView(imgV,params);

    // Some code downloading the image stream

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);


    imgV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
```

**Desired :**

[image: Desired result]

**Result :**

[image: Current result]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to stretch an image to the screen width while maintaining aspect ratio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991110/android-how-to-stretch-an-image-to-the-screen-width-while-maintaining-aspect-ra)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Thanks to @Julien and @js. 
Here is complete solution of ImageView that will stretch bitmap height preserving aspect ratio even if bitmap is smaller than ImageView.

```
public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {

    public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
         Drawable d = getDrawable();

         if(d!=null){
                 // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
                 int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                 int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
                 setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
         }else{
                 super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
         }
    }

}
```

You can use this class in your xml layouts instead ImageView.

```
<com.example.ResizableImageView
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/banner" />
```

Comment: I guess this deserves to be the final answer, but as @Js mentionned, you should null-check the Drawable. If you update your code, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: It perfectly work with UrlImageViewHelper. https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

Comment: this solution is ok for image where `height <= width` but otherwise you have to change order `int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth() / (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight());` right?

Comment: Silly that this can't be done from xml with all those scale options, but thank you!

Comment: One other thing to consider is the drawable might be a ColorDrawable which means getIntrinsicWidth() and getIntrinsicHeight() both return -1. This means the view will stretch to a square filling the space.. I'm not sure what it should do though since colors don't have a size.

Comment: Bad behavior when this ResizableImageView is inside layout with weight specified...

Comment: Brillliant ! Just what I wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 51):

You're probably looking for `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in xml or `imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true)` in Java.

Comment: That is in my code : imgV.setAdjustViewBounds(true); setAdjustViewBounds is only for ImageView, and I'd like a property like this for the RelativeLayout

Comment: Could you post your full xml layout? Small differences can make a large impact.

Comment: @Julien Have you found a solution? I have exactly the same problem.
Can you post the solution?

Comment: @Erik : I subclassed ImageView, I needed to override the onMeasure protected method, basically I changed directly the view's size keeping the aspect ratio (don't forget to super.onMeasure() before doing anything)

Comment: @Erik : Ok, I found it ! Hope it will help

Answer (score 8):

As I mentioned in a comment, I subclassed the ImageView. I found my code, here you go :

```
    protected class ResizableImageView extends ImageView
    {

        private Bitmap mBitmap;

        // Constructor

        public ResizableImageView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
        }


        // Overriden methods


          @Override 
          protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
                  int heightMeasureSpec) {
              if(mBitmap != null)
              {
                    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                    int height = width * mBitmap.getHeight() / mBitmap.getWidth();
                    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

              } 
              else
              {
                  super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,
                          heightMeasureSpec);
              }
              }

            @Override
            public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
            {
                mBitmap = bitmap;
                 super.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

    }
```

Comment: An improvement I made is not using a bitmap for getting height and width in `onMeasure` but using `getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()` and  `getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()` (of course with null-checking the drawable).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change your imgV width to "match_parent"

You should change the scale type to  imgV.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't change, center_inside has the same effect. And match_parent and fill_parent have the same value (-1) as said in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT

Comment: Ah, sorry, scratch that, i'm an idiot. At which point are you assigning layout parameters to your imageview?

Comment: When adding the view to the "banner" :     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    banner.addView(imgV,params);

Comment: This is a stab in the dark.. have you tried the following: params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT); params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

Comment: Nice idea, but it didn't work. The image view setAdjustViewBounds is apparently not working for the height

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of any more help. Good luck with your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I made a slight change to @Seraphim S's solution to account for cases where the image may be wide, and the view's bounds also wide (for example, rotating the device to landscape mode).

```
public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {
    public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();

        if (d != null) {

            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            if (width >= height) {
                width = (int) Math.ceil((float) height * (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth() / (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            } else {
                height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
            }

            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i got only one question d.getIntrinsicWidth() / d.getIntrinsicHeight()  = ??? divide and rule :D and u will get one big nothing :)