# How to set Width of the image (in ImageView) without changing the width of the ImageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

What I am trying to do is change the width of the image in a ImageView without affecting the width of ImageView.

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    |                                                              |
    |                                                              |
    |         ----------------------------------------------       |
    |         |                                            |       |
    |         |                                            |       |
    |         |    this is the image( change its width)    |       |
    |         |                                            |       |
    |         ----------------------------------------------       |
    |                                                              |
    |      this is imageView the width mustnt change               |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this ? Please Help?

Comment: try adding padding for the `imageView`.eg:`android:padding="1dp"`

Comment: how can i set padding imageView dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ScaleType for that.
Like,

```
imgV.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

and you can specify Padding property too.

see the link it might help you.

[Android ImageView adjusting parent's height and fitting width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554682/android-imageview-adjusting-parents-height-and-fitting-width)

Comment: working !! we can also use setMargins(280, 480,80 , 80); right?

Comment: No setMargins are for setting images inside the layout.. not image inside the imageview

Comment: Margin will leave space outside ImageView control while Padding will leave space within ImageView i.e. to its contents(ex. image).

Answer (score 0):

ImageView and image are not different. To show an image in an Android device we are using an ImageView. If you want to show an image at the centre of something, then wrap the image view with some layout and set the image inside that layout with some padding all the side you need.

Comment: But when we change the width of the imageview ,the image maintains its aspect ratio

Comment: it will. wrap the imageview with a layout and add the imageview with some padding.