# Android ImageView - Fill width and Resize to Maintain Aspect Ratio

Tags: java, android, resize, imageview, aspect-ratio

I have a row `View` that I am using in a `ListView`.

This `RowView` consists of an `ImageView` on the left and a `TextView` on the right in a horizontal `LinearLayout` where the image is given 40% of the space and the text the remaining 60%.

I want the layout to handle the resizing of the image in the `ImageView` in the following manner:

1. Stretch the image horizontally so that it fills up given 40% of the `LinearLayout`
2. Resize the `ImageView` vertically to maintain the original aspect ratio

This is my approach to the layouts:

```
protected class RowView extends LinearLayout {
public ImageView iv = null;
public TextView tv = null;

private LinearLayout.LayoutParams ivlp = null;
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvlp = null;

public RowView(Context ct) {
    super(ct);

    setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    // Create the views
    iv = new ImageView(ct);
    ivlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.4f);
    iv.setLayoutParams(ivlp);
    iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    tv = new TextView(ct);
    tvlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.4f);
    tv.setLayoutParams(tvlp);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT);

    // Add the views
    addView(iv);
    addView(tv);
}
```

}

The result I am getting is something like this:

[image]

From what I understand:

- The `MATCH_PARENT` is correctly forcing the image to horizontally stretch to fill the 40% space
- The `ImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true)` is supposed to allow any resizing of the `ImageView` that is necessary which is what I want. The problem is none of the `ImageView.ScaleType`'s seem to do what I want
- `ImageView.ScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY)` is not what I want because it doesn't maintain the aspect ratio. But all the others that do, don't seem to stretch the height of the `ImageView` (which is making `ImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true)` pretty much useless).

What am I doing wrong? It seems wrong that something this simple could be so difficult?

Or do I actually have to go to the effort of extending an `ImageView` and Overriding `onMeasure` to force the resizing and aspect ratio?

Or is there a clever trick with `Matrix` to get the job done?

Comment: this response is working for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12283909/888245

Comment: Check the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077325/scale-image-to-fill-imageview-width-and-keep-aspect-ratio

It worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the scale type completely. Also, I think you might have misunderstood what `setAdjustViewBounds` does. If an image is scaled, the bitmap in the `ImageView` is scaled, but not the `ImageView`. Setting `setAdjustViewBounds` to true will assure that the `ImageView`'s bounds will always match the drawn bitmap's bounds.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't achieve what I want. I want it to scale so that it does fill up the entire 40% of the row. Removing `ScaleType` does not scale the image at all which is not what I want. `setAdjustViewBounds` does seem right to me because I want the height bounds of the view to scale up or down as appropriate?