# Scale Image to fill ImageView width and keep aspect ratio

Tags: android, imageview

I have a `GridView`. The data of `GridView` is request from a server.

Here is the item layout in `GridView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/analysis_micon_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/half_activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/half_activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/half_activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/half_activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ranking_prod_pic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranking_rank_num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranking_prod_num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranking_prod_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I request data from server, get image url and load image to `Bitmap`

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromHttpUrl(String url) {
    try {
        return loadBitmapFromInputStream((InputStream) (new URL(url).getContent()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

and there is the code of `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method in adapter

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapUtil.loadBitmapFromHttpUrl(product.getHttpUrl());
prodImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The image size is `210*210`. I run my application on my Nexus 4. The image does fill `ImageView` width, but the `ImageView` height does not scale. `ImageView` does not show the whole image.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 636, accepted):

Without using any custom classes or libraries:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

`scaleType="fitCenter"` (default when omitted)

- will make it as wide as the parent allows and up/down-scale as needed keeping aspect ratio.

`scaleType="centerInside"`

- if the intrinsic width of `src` is smaller than parent width
  will center the image horizontally
- if the intrinsic width of `src` is larger than parent width
  will make it as wide as the parent allows and down-scale keeping aspect ratio.

It doesn't matter if you use `android:src` or `ImageView.setImage*` methods and the key is probably the `adjustViewBounds`.

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" does the trick

Comment: @JamesTan `fill_parent` for width is just a good practice, a fixed size works as well.

Comment: @TWiStErRob i realize it needs android:adjustViewBounds="true" with it, otherwise it does not fit accordingly for height. and yes, the width to fit parent is the complete version

Comment: Works like charm on API 19+, but not on API 16 (tested). Alex Semeniuk's custom view works on API 16 too.

Comment: @AshkanSarlak no problem for me in Api 16

Comment: android:adjustViewBounds="true"
is really a magic.. I was trying to solve this from last 3 days.

Comment: I needed `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to get the ratio to be even. Also `android:layout_gravity="center"` to center it in the view.

Comment: without a custom view, it may not work in all cases/on all devices with varying image sizes. I followed these instructions to get it to work consistently on all devices https://www.ryadel.com/en/android-proportionally-stretch-imageview-fit-whole-screen-width-maintaining-aspect-ratio/

Comment: Doesn't work for me. For some reason it gives white space for height.

Comment: Since we have 2020 please change `fill_parent` to `match_parent`

Comment: @F.Mysir whops , yes, it doesn't matter which one for the issue, but for spreading good practice, I totally agree.

Answer (score 43):

I like answer of arnefm but he made a small mistake (see comments) which I will try to correct:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * ImageView that keeps aspect ratio when scaled
 */
public class ScaleImageView extends ImageView {

  public ScaleImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public ScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public ScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    try {
      Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
      if (drawable == null) {
        setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
      } else {
        int measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (measuredHeight == 0 && measuredWidth == 0) { //Height and width set to wrap_content
          setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
        } else if (measuredHeight == 0) { //Height set to wrap_content
          int width = measuredWidth;
          int height = width *  drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
          setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else if (measuredWidth == 0){ //Width set to wrap_content
          int height = measuredHeight;
          int width = height * drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
          setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else { //Width and height are explicitly set (either to match_parent or to exact value)
          setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
  }

}
```

Thus your `ImageView` will be scaled properly and will have no dimension problems if (for instance) put inside of `ScrollView`

Comment: thx, i've found the solution, just below arnefm's answer, the first comment that i added. that `there` is a link

Answer (score 40):

I had a similar problem once. I solved it by making a custom ImageView.

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView
```

Then override the onMeasure method of the imageview. I did something like this I believe:

```
    @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    try {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
        } else {
            float imageSideRatio = (float)drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / (float)drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
            float viewSideRatio = (float)MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) / (float)MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            if (imageSideRatio >= viewSideRatio) {
                // Image is wider than the display (ratio)
                int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                int height = (int)(width / imageSideRatio);
                setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
            } else {
                // Image is taller than the display (ratio)
                int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
                int width = (int)(height * imageSideRatio);
                setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

This will stretch the image to fit the screen while maintaining the aspect ratio.

Comment: see [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991110/android-how-to-stretch-an-image-to-the-screen-width-while-maintaining-aspect-ra). the first answer

Comment: Well, this answer is not accurate. Consider situation where you set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. In this case `MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)` will be `0` and your `viewSideRatio` will result in `Infinity` (no need to wonder, Java float allows such values.) In this case both your `height` and `width` will be `0`.

Comment: For me to make the fill work i needed to swap (imageSideRatio >= viewSideRatio) to (imageSideRatio < viewSideRatio).. otherwise a good answer

Answer (score 29):

Use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

Comment: Not exactly what the question was asking for, but exactly what I needed!

Comment: Can you elaborate @Jameson? Do you mean Android versions?

Comment: If I use centerCrop, the image gets cut on top and bottom a little.

Answer (score 11):

FOR IMAGE VIEW (set these parameters)

```
android:layout_width     = "match_parent"
android:layout_height    = "wrap_content"
android:scaleType        = "fitCenter"
android:adjustViewBounds = "true"
```

Now whatever the size of the image is there, it's width will match the parent and height will be according to match the ratio. I have tested this and I am 100% sure.

we want this --> [image: adjustViewBound = true]

not this -->     [image: adjustViewBound = false]

```
// Results will be: 
Image width -> stretched as match parent
Image height -> according to image width (maximum to aspect ratio)

// like the first one
```

Answer (score 9):

I did something similar to the above and then banged my head against the wall for a few hours because it did not work inside a `RelativeLayout`.  I ended up with the following code:

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ScaledImageView extends ImageView {
    public ScaledImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final Drawable d = getDrawable();

        if (d != null) {
            int width;
            int height;
            if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
                height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
                width = (int) Math.ceil(height * (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth() / d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            } else {
                width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                height = (int) Math.ceil(width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth());
            }
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

And then to prevent `RelativeLayout` from ignoring the measured dimension I did this:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/something">

        <com.example.ScaledImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 9):

Yo don't need any java code. You just have to :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

The key is in the match parent for width and height

Comment: centerCrop actually cuts some part of the image.

Answer (score 7):

This will not be applicable if you set image as background in ImageView, need to set at src(android:src).

Thanks.

Comment: Saved my sanity, this extra tidbit.

Answer (score 6):

To create an image with width equals screen width, and height proportionally set according to aspect ratio, do the following.

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                        // creating the image that maintain aspect ratio with width of image is set to screenwidth.
                        int width = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
                        int diw = resource.getWidth();
                        if (diw > 0) {
                            int height = 0;
                            height = width * resource.getHeight() / diw;
                            resource = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, width, height, false);
                        }
                                              imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is the best answer i found, i searching for 2 days, thanks fathima

Answer (score 2):

Use these properties in ImageView to keep aspect ratio:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: fitXY does NOT keep the aspect ratio. It stretches the image to fit the width and height of the layout exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do what you're doing by manually loading the images, but I would very very strongly recommend taking a look at [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

I recently integrated it into my project and I have to say its fantastic. Does all the worrying about making things asynchronous, resizing, caching images for you.  It's really easy to integrate and set up. Within 5 minutes you can probably get it doing what you want.

Example code:

```
//ImageLoader config
DisplayImageOptions displayimageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showStubImage(R.drawable.downloadplaceholder).cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc().showImageOnFail(R.drawable.loading).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).
            defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayimageOptions).memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache()).discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)).build();

    if (ImageLoader.getInstance().isInited()) {
        ImageLoader.getInstance().destroy();
    }
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    imageLoadingListener = new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
            Log.i("Failed to Load " + s, failReason.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

        }
    };

//Imageloader usage
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    if (orientation == 1) {
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width / 6, width / 6));
    } else {
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(height / 6, height / 6));
    }
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageLoader.displayImage(SERVER_HOSTNAME + "demos" + demo.getPathRoot() + demo.getRootName() + ".png", imageView, imageLoadingListener);
```

This can lazy load the images, fit them correctly to the size of the imageView showing a placeholder image while it loads, and showing a default icon if loading fails and caching the resources.

-- I should also add that this current config keeps the image aspect ratio, hence applicable to your original question

Answer (score 1):

Try this: it solved the problem for me

```
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: How is this answer different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37044123/1101730? What is more it's a wrong answer as fitXY does NOT keep the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Just use UniversalImageLoader and set

```
DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
    .build();
```

and no scale settings on ImageView

Answer (score 0):

try with this simple line... add this line in your xml code in image view tag with out adding any dependency
android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: fitXY does not maintain the aspect ratio so the image will likely be stretched

Answer (score 0):

use android:ScaleType="fitXY" im ImageView xml

Comment: fitXY does not maintain the aspect ratio so the image will likely be stretched

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I found the reason for this is because you need to calculate the `dp`. Android studio is calculating the `ImageView` when you load it from the `drawable`, but when you are using another method, like loading from **bitmap** the `dp` is not automatically accounted for,

Here is my xml

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageViewer"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"//dp is not automaticly updated, when loading from a other source
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
  tools:srcCompat="@drawable/a8" />
```

I'm using Kotlin, and loading drawable from an asset file, here's how I calculate this

```
val d = Drawable.createFromStream(assets.open("imageData/${imageName}.png"), null)
bitHeight = d.minimumHeight//get the image height
imageViewer.layoutParams.height = (bitHeight * resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()//set the height
imageViewer.setImageDrawable(d)//set the image from the drawable
imageViewer.requestLayout()//here I apply it to the layout
```