# Retrieve image layout dimensions in Android

Tags: android, xml

How can I set the width and height of an ImageView before loading the image with, for example, setBitmapImage()?

The point is that I have a GridView with variable number of columns and I do need to stretch the width of the images by preserving the aspect ratio, and, since I load the images in an asynchronous manner, I do want to prepare the layouts before loading the images, that is, width and height of the ImageView.

Comment: progrmatically set the height and width of that loyout ..did u got some error while doing that?

Comment: Sorry let me reformulate the question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`ImageView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29)'s [`ScaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

You can chose one of these :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
yourLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not an answer, it's just a line of code that does not solve my problem.

Comment: A line of code can solve your question dont underestimate it ;) Anyway  if you want to keep ratio you can use scaleType property of imageview, it has a lot options to pick one http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Hi Onur! thanks for your comment! anyway, the point is that I am trying to retrieve the width of a layout but the result is always -1 (wrap_content, I guess) but, at the end, this is not the actual width. How can I measure the real width at a concrete moment?

Comment: BitmapFactory can be used to get width and height, how you get those images?

Comment: I do know the bitmap size, I just need to know the width of the parent layout of the ImageView in order to stretch it

Comment: if your parent view is fill_parent then getting the screen size will give you the parent width, you can get screen size Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look here, there was a similar question asked earlier today:

[Scale Image to fill ImageView width and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077325/scale-image-to-fill-imageview-width-and-keep-aspect-ratio/18077714#18077714)

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

know the height and the width of the image, but You the following code to retrieve the layout dimension in the ANDROID

yourLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to set a fixed width and height