# Can't manage to resize image and keep the ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

My goal is simple : have a 16/9 ratio image in an imageView. I use a png image which dimensions are 16x9. 2 possibilities for my app :

- portrait : width fixed, has to scale height
- landscape : height fixed, has to scale width

The first one works fine with this layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/welcomeRootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/welcomePilotingFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/black_16_9e" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Other stuff that aren't relevant -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

This gives me what i want : my red cornered image is resized

[image]

Now the fun part begins : landscape: Here's my layout (symetric off portrait) :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/welcomeLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/welcomePilotingFrame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff00ff00" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/black_16_9e_border" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/welcomePilotingFrame" />

    </RelativeLayout>

<!-- Other stuff that aren't relevant -->

</LinearLayout>
```

And now, the imageView understands it has to be all its parent high, but does't resize its width and so doesn't keep my 16/9 ratio !

[image]

Am I missing something ?

Comment: what scaleType have you try?

Comment: All of them, no better result

Comment: tried "matrix" with properly transformed Matrix?

Comment: I didn't try matrix (and gonna try now), but I don't understand why portrait's behaviour is what I expect and landscape's is not, since both logics are exactly the same.

Comment: fitXY cannot work as it doesnt save aspect ratio (it uses Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL)

Comment: well for portrait it does work with adjustViewBounds property

Comment: so what is the size (getWidth/hetHeight) in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout_width of second framelayout to match_parent. Also scale-type = fitxy changes aspect ratio of the image. Change it to FIT_START

Comment: No I can't, there's an element that has to be at the right of the image. And if I go and put fitStart, the image keeps it original size 16x9, and I want it to be as high as the relativeLayout parent

Comment: I said change the width of that second layout(one that is right of image) to match_parent not the image's width

Comment: Same result : image's height is ok, not resized width. Even if I remove that right frame, imageView doesn't fill width

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077325/scale-image-to-fill-imageview-width-and-keep-aspect-ratio should help you

Comment: Indeed i was thinking one layer to high. I changed to resize my image in the onMeasure. Thanks !