# How to maintain the aspect ratio of the image and fill the screen width?

Tags: android, imageview, aspect-ratio, adjustviewbounds

I am trying to resize an image by keeping the aspect ratio. It should be just large enough to fill the screen width and if necessary some of the image should be off-screen.

[here is a picture of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV1Fk.png)

I tried

> android:adjustViewBounds

but when the image is larger than screen it fits image into imageView and not filling the width.

And I also don't want to use :

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Here  is my complete code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageBackgroundAboutFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/about_us_background"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` with `android:adjustViewBounds`

**UPDATE**

I think you should do some trial and errors :

[How to scale an Image in ImageView to keep the aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521959/how-to-scale-an-image-in-imageview-to-keep-the-aspect-ratio)

[Scale Image to fill ImageView width and keep aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077325/scale-image-to-fill-imageview-width-and-keep-aspect-ratio)

So many possible fix, but i dont really sure which one will work for you (my answer working for me but not for you - for example).

Comment: I tried it, but it is not keeping aspect ratio:

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageBackgroundAboutFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/about_us_background"/>

Comment: Hmm..its keeping the image's ratio in my case

Comment: thanx, but it doesn't.
you think the parent is important?
I use a relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

updtae your imageview like this..

remove scaleType and adjustViewBounds.. and make layout_height as match_parent

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageBackgroundAboutFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/about_us_background"/>
```

Comment: thanx but it does not fill entire page if image is tall.