# Picasso and custom ImageView causing Out of memory error

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-image, picasso

I am having Out Of Memory errors with Picasso as below.

My ImageView is slightly special, I am using my own custom ScaleImageView class that extends an ImageView and while downloading the image from URL makes sure that the imageview fits the width of the parent, while taking the appropriate height to keep aspect ratio same

I tried doing it via adjustBounds = true, however, only writing a custom class as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077325/scale-image-to-fill-imageview-width-and-keep-aspect-ratio) worked for me

The custom ImageView scales the ImageView on the onMeasure() function according to the drawable size. However, I see that on scrolling through the listview that contains various such images (inside the feeds), I keep getting out of memory error by running out of memory.

**Not sure this can be of help:** In my server response where I also receive the height and width of the image as represented in the URL in pixels. Is there a way to use it and not do the `Drawable drawable = getDrawable();` line to avoid inflating the full picture in the memory? I am not sure what is the approach I should take

### Picasso image loading code

```
ImageView contentImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_image_content_iv);
if (!(feed.getImage_content().equals(""))) {
    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(feed.getImage_content())//.resize(size.x, size.y)
            .into(contentImage);
}
```

### My custom Imageview class

```
public class ScaleImageView extends ImageView {

    public ScaleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        try {
            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null) {
                setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
            } else {
                int measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                int measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
                if (measuredHeight == 0 && measuredWidth == 0) { //Height and width set to wrap_content
                    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
                } else if (measuredHeight == 0) { //Height set to wrap_content
                    int width = measuredWidth;
                    int height = width *  drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
                    Log.d("PictureDimension", "width = " + width + " height= " + height);

                } else if (measuredWidth == 0){ //Width set to wrap_content
                    int height = measuredHeight;
                    int width = height * drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
                } else { //Width and height are explicitly set (either to match_parent or to exact value)
                    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

}
```

### Out of memory error logcat

```
05-14 20:09:56.008  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 96MB/96MB, paused 411us total 13.589ms
05-14 20:09:56.008  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 12.512ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.024  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.025  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 2(32KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 379us total 16.651ms
05-14 20:09:56.025  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 29.172ms for cause Background
05-14 20:09:56.025  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 29.201ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.026  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1433612 byte allocation with 6034 free bytes and 5KB until OOM"
05-14 20:09:56.029  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 32.200ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.029  14813-14825/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 20.350ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.029  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 16.402ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.057  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.057  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 26(4KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(80KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 390us total 28.343ms
05-14 20:09:56.057  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 60.759ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.058  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1406KB allocation
05-14 20:09:56.085  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.085  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(256B) AllocSpace objects, 1(32KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 497us total 26.748ms
05-14 20:09:56.086  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 56.622ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.093  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1440012 byte allocation with 58538 free bytes and 57KB until OOM"
05-14 20:09:56.108  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.108  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 395(52KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 552us total 22.198ms
05-14 20:09:56.108  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 78.980ms for cause Background
05-14 20:09:56.112  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 68.273ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.129  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.129  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 91(3KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(80KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 462us total 16.542ms
05-14 20:09:56.129  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 33.219ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.129  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 58.237ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.129  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 102.016ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.129  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 15.446ms for cause Background
05-14 20:09:56.129  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 14.857ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.130  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 3MB allocation
05-14 20:09:56.137  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 7.177ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.158  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.158  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 158(10KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(32KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 371us total 20.641ms
05-14 20:09:56.158  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 27.774ms for cause Background
05-14 20:09:56.158  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 26.815ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.158  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 26.467ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.158  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 22.363ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.158  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 14.109ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.175  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 3240012 byte allocation with 68278 free bytes and 66KB until OOM"
05-14 20:09:56.175  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-14 20:09:56.187  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.187  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 149(24KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 422us total 28.263ms
05-14 20:09:56.187  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 28.022ms for cause Background
05-14 20:09:56.187  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 28.050ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.190  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 14.227ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.190  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 13.799ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.194  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 6.880ms for cause Background
05-14 20:09:56.195  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 18.362ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.208  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 10.051ms
05-14 20:09:56.209  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.209  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 32(11KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 402us total 11.190ms
05-14 20:09:56.209  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 21.462ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.224  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.224  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 37(4KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 312us total 14.649ms
05-14 20:09:56.224  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 32.955ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.235  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1400KB allocation
05-14 20:09:56.246  14813-14823/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 8.556ms
05-14 20:09:56.246  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.246  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(128B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 416us total 21.800ms
05-14 20:09:56.247  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 56.130ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.247  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 50.960ms for cause Background
05-14 20:09:56.247  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 37.690ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.253  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 43.011ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.267  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.267  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 346us total 13.787ms
05-14 20:09:56.267  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 32.684ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.279  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1406KB allocation
05-14 20:09:56.292  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.292  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 392us total 24.267ms
05-14 20:09:56.292  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 44.506ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.296  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 47.972ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.336  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 40.090ms
05-14 20:09:56.336  14813-14930/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1433612 byte allocation with 13350 free bytes and 13KB until OOM"
05-14 20:09:56.337  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.337  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 408us total 41.124ms
05-14 20:09:56.337  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 86.089ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.338  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1400KB allocation
05-14 20:09:56.341  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 86.825ms for cause Background
05-14 20:09:56.351  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 6.123ms
05-14 20:09:56.352  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.352  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 15.389ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.363  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.363  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9(288B) AllocSpace objects, 1(32KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 428us total 11.437ms
05-14 20:09:56.364  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 25.975ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.384  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.385  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 30(14KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 275us total 20.834ms
05-14 20:09:56.385  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 105.581ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.403  14813-14931/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1433612 byte allocation with 30880 free bytes and 30KB until OOM"
05-14 20:09:56.416  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.416  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 89(6KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 805us total 31.446ms
05-14 20:09:56.416  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 63.369ms for cause Background
05-14 20:09:56.416  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 62.037ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.416  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 45.158ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.417  14813-14940/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 1440012 byte allocation with 28640 free bytes and 27KB until OOM"
05-14 20:09:56.423  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 5.411ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.434  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.434  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 88(18KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(96KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 326us total 9.896ms
05-14 20:09:56.434  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 10.063ms for cause Alloc
05-14 20:09:56.434  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 10.143ms for cause Background
05-14 20:09:56.435  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug E/ACRA﹕ ACRA caught a InflateException for com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.base.BaseCard.getInnerView(BaseCard.java:112)
            at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.Card.getInnerView(Card.java:282)
            at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative.setupMainView(CardViewNative.java:479)
            at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative.buildUI(CardViewNative.java:374)
            at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative.setCard(CardViewNative.java:330)
            at it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.CardArrayAdapter.getView(CardArrayAdapter.java:171)
            at com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.views.EmCardArrayAdapter.getView(EmCardArrayAdapter.java:24)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1455)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1455)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:1743
05-14 20:09:56.436  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/ACRA﹕ Building report
05-14 20:09:56.453  14813-14828/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 14.414ms
05-14 20:09:56.454  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
05-14 20:09:56.454  14813-14929/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 38(4KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(29KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 307us total 15.662ms
05-14 20:09:56.457  14813-14813/com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.debug D/ACRA﹕ Using default Report Fields
```

Comment: The exception seems to be a InflateException at BaseCard.java:112 rather than OOM I suppose?

Comment: Ostensibly yes, but the logcat in a lot of cases show - 'Caused by' OOM - failed to allocate XX bytes while YY is available kind of proper OOM log

Comment: My wild guess will be a memory leak somewhere in your application. Perhaps try to run memory profile and see what it gives.

Comment: Thanks I studied the code using LeakCanary and it gave no memory leaks