# subsampling-scale-image-view setRotation doesn't occupy whole screen

Tags: android, image

I want to toggle 90-degree rotation when an image is tapped:

```
@UiThread // Android Annotations
void loadImage(ImageSource uri) {
    image.setMinimumScaleType(SCALE_TYPE_CENTER_CROP);
    image.setMaxScale(8);
    image.setImage(uri); // I've tried the ImageViewState variant
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (image.getRotation() < 1) {
                image.setRotation(90);
            } else {
                image.setRotation(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Where the `image` is defined in a fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**It's working, but the 90-degree rotated image does not occupy the whole screen. It has white background at the top and bottom.**

[image: Original image]

[image: Rotated image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Will this code work for you?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146058/1163224

Comment: @ProblemSlover nope, my issue is with a 3rd party library, https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view sorry I forgot to mention it

Comment: Anyway, Well you can create a subclass of the image view and to override method which is responsible for displaying an image and try to apply/ the code suggested above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `setOrientation()`, not `setRotation()`. The latter method belongs to `View`.