# ImageView not covering complete width of the parent CardView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-cardview

I have a parent `LinearLayout` inside which I have 2 `CardViews`. I have an `ImageView` inside each `CardView`. When I load image in any of `ImageView` its not taking the complete width of the `CardView`. There is a slight white gap between the `ImageView` and `CardView`. How can I overlap the `ImageView` completely over the `CardView`? Here is my layout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/adhaarCardFrontUpload"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/adhaar_height"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/upload_adhaar_front"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/adhaarCardFrontImage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/adhaarCardBackUpload"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/adhaar_height"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:text="@string/upload_adhaar_back"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/adhaarCardBackImage"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try chaning imageview width to match_parent

Answer (score 2):

Change adjustViewBounds to false.

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="false"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

If you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable then set this to true.

Comment: Actually I am talking about the `ImageView` with `id="adhaarCardBackImage"`. I have it as match_parent but still it doesn't take the complete width of the parent `CardView`

Comment: Did you try toggling adjustviewbounds?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**`MATCH_PARENT`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT).

> Special value for the height or width requested by a View.
>   MATCH_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent,
>   minus the parent's padding, if any.

Try this way,

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add" 
  />
```

Try with

```
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: Actually I am talking about the ImageView with `id="adhaarCardBackImage"`. I have it as match_parent but still it doesn't take the complete width of the parent `CardView`

Comment: Add `fitXY` there instead of `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: I tried that as well. It gave me more bad results. `centerCrop` gave good results but there is slight gap at the sides of the CardView. `fitXY` didnt even come close to the width of the `CardView`

Comment: Ok. I will check nextday.

Comment: @XoXo Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077325/scale-image-to-fill-imageview-width-and-keep-aspect-ratio

Comment: gone through this link before I posted the question

Comment: @XoXo Any solutions ?

Comment: Nope. Still trying to figure out what is the mistake.