# Resize image to fit ImageButton

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I'm really new at this and I'm trying to load profile pics from gallery and camera into ImageButton. I'm able to add image from gallery but the image does not fit completely into the ImageButton. Some space still gets left out from the imagebutton. I want the image to automatically fit into imagebutton.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sam.sport.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LL1" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity class is as below:-**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton ib;
    private static Bitmap Image = null;
    private static final int GALLERY = 1;
    private static Bitmap rotateImage = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ib.setImageBitmap(null);
                if (Image != null)
                    Image.recycle();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), GALLERY);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY && resultCode != 0) {
            Uri mImageUri = data.getData();             
            try {

                Image = Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mImageUri);
                if (getOrientation(getApplicationContext(), mImageUri) != 0) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(getOrientation(getApplicationContext(), mImageUri));
                    if (rotateImage != null)
                        rotateImage.recycle();
                    rotateImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(Image, 0, 0, Image.getWidth(), Image.getHeight(), matrix,
                            true);
                    ib.setImageBitmap(rotateImage);

                } else
                    ib.setImageBitmap(Image);   
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
        /* it's on the external media. */
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION }, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
            return -1;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getInt(0);
    }   


    }
```

Comment: use center crop in you image button xml

Comment: spaces are on top and left side ? right?

Comment: @Arslan spaces are with the whole border of ImageButton. On all 4 sides.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to Drawable then use `setBackgroundDrawable` insted of `setImageBitmap`

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(rotateImage);
ib.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Tried your way but its not happening. Still showing the imagebutton border space and the image is in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Use below line of code for re-sizing your bitmap

```
 Bitmap BITMAP_IMAGE = Bitmap.createBitmap(IMAGE_VIEW.getWidth(),IMAGE_VIEW.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
 Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BITMAP_IMAGE, 100, 100, false); ////Here BITMAP_IMAGE is your bitmap which you want to resize
```

Comment: That's not working. Did like: `Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotateImage, 100, 100, false);
     ib.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);`

Comment: Is it not resize your bitmap image??

Comment: Yes. The image is still smaller than the actual 100dp*100dp ImageButton border.

Comment: @sam ... I have updated the answer,please check it and let me know

Comment: Is IMAGE_VIEW the ImageButton or the selected image?

Comment: Yes bro...try it..It is IMAGE BUTTON

Comment: I tried. Not working. Also, Bitmap `BITMAP_IMAGE` Y? Shouldn't it be `Bitmap resizedBitmap` like below object?

Comment: Sorry @sam ... I did not get waht you said...can you please tell in more specific way??

Comment: The 1st line: Bitmap `BITMAP_IMAGE` = ......      Here is BITMAP_IMAGE the object ? Cuz in the 2nd line BITMAP_IMAGE is the selected image.

Comment: Yes obeys.. bro..It is a object of BITMAP

Answer (score 0):

Get the imageButton height and width

```
Bitmap bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Image, ib_width, ib_height, true);
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapScaled);
ib.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Keep in mind about OOM exception.

To get imageButton height and width look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411975/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-view-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the perfect solution. To resize imageview I used the below code as provided in the [[Android ImageView adjusting parent's height and fitting width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554682/android-imageview-adjusting-parents-height-and-fitting-width/12283909#12283909)

```html
public class ResizableImageView extends ImageView {

    public ResizableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
         Drawable d = getDrawable();

         if(d!=null){
                 // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
                 int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                 int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
                 setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
         }else{
                 super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
         }
    }

}
```

][1](http://link.)