# Stretch the image dynamically depending on row height of listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-imageview

I have a row in a list view with 3 fields. Icon to the left, a header and a description about 3-4 lines below the header. Initially description is hidden. On click of the header the visibility is changed from Gone to Visible or vice versa. When the description is visible, I want to stretch image view (icon) to the height of the expanded row. How do I do this ? I have given

`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

`android:scaleType="fitXY" to <ImageView />`

If I change, height of icon to LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT in the program, the images stretches more than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using gravity's `FILL`, `FILL_HORIZONTAL`, and `FILL_VERTICAL` feature. Take a look a [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) for further detail on this.

Comment: There is no property called android:gravity for ImageView.

Comment: This is what it should look like when you want to make it FILL: `android:layout_gravity="fill"`. You just put that under the layout of the imageview. If you want to make it FILL_VERTICAL or FILL_HORIZONTAL, you do this: `android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"` or `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"`.

Comment: I have a relative layout around the listview. If I give android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" the image is pre-stretched. I want it to stretch to the size of the row when description is displayed after I click on header.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991110/android-how-to-stretch-an-image-to-the-screen-width-while-maintaining-aspect-rat) website that might help you accomplish what you want.

Comment: You can also use `android:layout_weight=".70"`, which in this case expands/shrinks the view to fill 70% of the space it is provided.

Comment: I am using a relative layout. So layout_weight isnt available. I tried using ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener. I get the new row height here but setting the height of the image using `img.getLayoutParams().height= NEW_HEIGHT` changes the height only when there is a change in row height next time, not until then.

Comment: You could create a linear layout that contains the relative layout. And then set the relative layout to fill its parent. This way you can use the layout_weight feature of a linear layout and you can still use a relative layout for your views.

Comment: The thing is, I dont want to increase the width at all. Only the height. Giving layout_weight will increase width also.

Comment: What if you set `android:maxWidth="10dip"` to set the maximum width of the layout. That way the layout_weight will only increase the height since it has reached its maximum width.