# ImageView: fill horizontal maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, imageview

I need an `ImageView` scale it image until fill the parent horizontally.

If the imageview background is red, and the rest of the content (below the image) is the green I'm looking for the result shown by the **Picture 1**. That result is obtained automatically if the image width is higher than the screen width.

But if is a small picture like in the picture 2. the best result I can get is the **picture 3** (setting the ImageView width and height to **fill_parent** and the scaleType to **FitStart**

The picture 4 is obtained setting `height= wrap_content, width= fill_parent`, `scaleType= CenterCrop`. It should scale vertically to show the entire image, but as the scaleType says it crops it.

Any ideas for getting the picture 1 even if the image is small?

Will grant a bounty of 50 to a working answer

[image]

Comment: Do you have to do it from XML or can it be code as well?

Comment: No problem if the solution is with code

Comment: I know this is an old question, but i've been doing some research due the same problem that you have and this works for me. Take a look at this thread, first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991110/android-how-to-stretch-an-image-to-the-screen-width-while-maintaining-aspect-ra

Answer (score 4):

I found an easy solution that works really good for me. Set width and height as you wish, e.g.:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Then you also set this setting:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

"adjustViewBounds" defaults to false (which I find odd) but setting it makes it easy to fill the image in the imageview.

Answer (score 1):

It's doable without custom classes. This is the result I've gained with small image:
[image]

With large image:
[image]

You have to use `RelativeLayout` in order for this to work, but you can combine it with `LinearLayout` to achieve whatever you need. Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >
            <Button
                android:text="button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Button
                android:text="button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Button
                android:text="button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/cat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_above="@id/button_container"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The trick is that you set it to fill the screen but it has to be above the other layouts. This way you achieve everything you need.

Comment: it's awesome to do this with out custom classes!! I'm out of luck cos I need to place it at the bottom, just right on the contrary ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CustomImageView extends android.widget.ImageView {

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void fitYUniformly() {
        final Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null) return;

        final int dwidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        final int dheight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        if (dwidth == -1 || dheight == -1) return;

        int vheight = this.getHeight();
        float scale = (float) vheight / (float) dheight;

        final int vwidth = (int) (dwidth * scale);
        scale(scale, vwidth, vheight);
    }

    public void fitXUniformly(int parentWidth) {
        final Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null) return;

        final int dwidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        final int dheight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        if (dwidth == -1 || dheight == -1) return;

        int vwidth = parentWidth;// here,you need to pass the width of parentview
    //  int vwidth = this.getWidth();           
        float scale = (float) vwidth / (float) dwidth;

        final int vheight = (int) (dheight * scale);
        scale(scale, vwidth, vheight);
    }

    private void scale(float scale, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = this.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = newWidth;
        params.height = newHeight;
        this.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        this.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }

}
```

**Note:**

Don't forget to call `fitXUniformly(parentWidth);` . here, `parentWidth` will be the width of `CustomImageView`'s parent.

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: does it mean your code doesn't work out of the box? if so, where's the suggested place to put `fitXUniformly`? (as mentioned in your note)