# Android: How to stretch an background drawable to the screen width while cropping it vertically and maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: android, background, drawable, crop, stretch

I have a background drawable and I want to stretch it horizontally to the screen width and maintain its aspect ratio, but I want to crop it vertically since it will go out of the bottom of the screen.

I can't use an ImageView for some reason and have to use a BitmapDrawable, any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean you can't use `ImageView`?

Comment: because other views need to overlay on the layout which has this background set

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991110/android-how-to-stretch-an-image-to-the-screen-width-while-maintaining-aspect-ra?rq=1