# Set margins of ImageView whit scaleType="fitCenter"

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have an activity in portrait mode. Inside the activity I want to visualize an image (not matter dimensions and proportions) that automatically fit the exactly width of screen (imagine a normal gallery app).
To do this, I place the *ImageView* in a *RelativeLayout*, in this way:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/greatImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and it's ok, BUT now I need to move the *ImageView* a certain amount of *DP* down (ex 300dp) so that the bottom of *ImageView* comes out of the screen (this is because later I will start an animation that will bring the ImageView in the correct position).

If I set *layout_marginTop="300dp"* for *RelativeLayout* the *ImageView* will be scaled down, and is boundaries stop matching the parent width.

**I know that I can set the *scaleType* of *ImageView* to center**, but this way the *ImageView* stop scaling correctly to adeguate his dimensions to the screen.

The only solution that I found is to wrap *RelativeLayout* inside a *ScrollView*, and move the *marginTop* of the same *ScrollView*.

There is another way?
Hope I explained my problem, thanks.

Comment: android:scaleType="fitxy"

Comment: What if you also set layout_marginBottom="-300dp" and animate both properties?

Comment: @vokilam so simple… :D if you set your comment as an answer, I'll check it as the correct one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you also set `layout_marginBottom="-300dp"` and animate both properties?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "scaleType" - best thing to do is use java (unless you are required to do this with XML - which may mean something more creative, if it's even possible).

Check this out:

[Android: How to stretch an image to the screen width while maintaining aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991110/android-how-to-stretch-an-image-to-the-screen-width-while-maintaining-aspect-ra)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I prefer to use XML for now, but your suggest is great.

Answer (score 1):

Please try setting your `layout_marginBottom` as `-300dp`.

This will push your layout out of the screen from bottom without altering the view's height.

Comment: Noticed it later that @vokilam had already shared this solution in comments