# How to make image fit the whole width screen without blank space in android?

Tags: android

Tried to make image taken to fit the whole screen size width, and top

Picture output should be like this:

[image: should be like this]

The output on the screen of my app is as below with blank space on top, left and right side.

[image: Image output 2]

My XML for the activity layout is below:

```
         <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/vestGlavnaSlikaLayout"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_marginRight="-20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:background="@android:color/black"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tekstglavnevesti"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

My code to display the image:

```
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v. findViewById(R.id.iv);
     Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(slikeZaVesti.get(0))
                            .into(iv); // jpg tag is pasrsed from html
```

As you l might observe, there are blank spaces at both left and right side of the image. Any way to make the image fit perfectly onto the screen?

Comment: That doesn't look like the full layout for the Activity. Can you post the rest?

Comment: The code is to long to fit to comment:(

Comment: You should be able to edit your question.

Comment: I will suggest to try to use this solution it will work great.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991110/android-how-to-stretch-an-image-to-the-screen-width-while-maintaining-aspect-ra?rq=1

Comment: Show the whole layout please, I think your top parent has margins or paddings. And remove those negative margins...

Comment: remove paddings from your parent layout

Comment: I dont have any paddings in my parent layout. . When i remove negative margins nothing happens.